# Making a default value a property

Tags: python, properties, meta-programming, memoization

I recently asked a [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28961924/321973), looking for a way to more easily turn a class attribute into a `@property`, but only if no other value has been provided to the class constructor. A simple way to do this is

> ```
> class Demo(object):
>     def __init__(self, value=None):
>         self._value = value
>
>     @property
>     def value(self):
>         if self._value is None:
>             # some calculations to get value
>             self._value = value
>         return self._value
> ```

which I considered quite some overhead, so my question there asked for a decorator implementing this, and I came up with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28961925/321973)

```
import functools

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/28961925/321973
def property_if_None_generator(f, cached=False):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(self):
        value = self.__getattribute__('_' + f.__name__)
        if value is not None:
            return value
        else:
            return f(self)
    if cached:
        wrapped = functools.lru_cache()(wrapped)
    return property(wrapped)

property_if_None = lambda f: property_if_None_generator(f, cached=False)
cached_property_if_None = lambda f: property_if_None_generator(f, cached=True)
```

then the question's example would turn into

> ```
> class Demo(object):
>     def __init__(self, value=None):
>         self._value = value
>
>     @chached_property_if_None
>     def value(self):
>         # some calculations to get value
>         return value
> ```

Now I would appreciate any feedback on both the decorator itself and whether this is actually acceptable as opposed to the non-decorator version mentioned above. I'm especially concerned about the question whether it is a good idea to implicitly use the underscore-prepended attribute/property-name.

I have also considered making things even shorter by using another decorator (or even a metaclass) such that the `__init__` wouldn't even have to do the `self._value = value` assignment, I'd also appreciate opinions on that.

**edit** Since the SO-answer merely received a downvote without comment so far, I'd really appreciate feedback on this...

Comment: Just to clarify — you wish to only support read-only properties?

Comment: If this *is* readonly, why wouldn't you handle the `None` case in (or *from*) the initialiser? Then the property becomes trivial.

Comment: @200_success Good point, yes, it's read-only, and...

Comment: ...@jonrsharpe it's a lengthy calculation if no value is provided (I only stated that [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28961924/321973), sorry), so it'd be best in a separate method anyway "- and if it's already a method, why not make it a property directly?" was my thought then